# Выборка из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток. 
Помогите решить задачу с MySQL (знаком довольно плохо):

Есть 5 таблиц:

```
games (id, name, info)
platforms (id, name, info)
categories (im, name, info)
games_platforms_assign (game_id, platform_id)
games_categories_assign (game_id, category_id)
```

Соответственно, таблица games имеет связи многие-ко-многим с таблицами platforms и categories. Необходимо выбирать все games, относящиеся к заданным platforms.name и categories.name. Делаю так:

```
SELECT games.*
FROM games
  JOIN games_platforms_assign On games.id = games_platforms_assign.game_id
  JOIN platforms ON platforms.name = 'pc' AND games_platforms_assign.platform_id = platforms.id
  JOIN games_categories_assign ON games.id = games_categories_assign.game_id
  JOIN categories ON categories.name = 'action' AND games_categories_assign.category_id = categories.id;
```

Результат выборки соответствует ожиданиям, но скорость выполнения ужасно медленна. Пробовал с помощью вложенных SELECTов - получалось в разы медленнее.

Как переделать запрос для существенного ускорения выполнения? Или, в крайнем случае, как лучше переделать структуру базы данных под подобные запросы?

Comment: Да индексов небось нет, оттого и тормоза. EXPLAIN в помощь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы перенёс изменяемые условия в WHERE. Это(в некоторых сценариях) позволит переиспользовать результат prepare.
Использование псевдонимов таблиц

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, g.info
FROM games g
  JOIN games_platforms_assign gp On g.id = gp.game_id
  JOIN platforms p ON gp.platform_id = p.id
  JOIN games_categories_assign gc ON g.id = gc.game_id
  JOIN categories c ON gc.category_id = c.id
WHERE p.name = ? AND c.name = ?
```

Абсолютно необходимо создать индексы(а лучше `foreign keys`) на поля-связки (`game_id`, `platform_id`, `category_id`) и индексы на поля поиска(`name`).

После этого можно смотреть `EXPLAIN`, чтобы убедиться в том какие индексы используются, при необходимости можно добавить композитных индексов.

Comment: извините, пока писал не обратил внимание, что вы уже запостили ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.id g.name g.info
FROM games g
LTFT JOIN games_platforms_assign gpa ON (gpa.game_id = g.id)
LEFT JOIN games_categories_assign gca ON (gca.game_id = g.id)
LEFT JOIN platforms p ON (p.id = gpa.game_id)
LEFT JOIN categories c ON (c.id = gca.game_id)
WHERE p.name = .... AND c.name = ....
```

Comment: А на зачем **LEFT** JOIN? чтобы сервер лишнего попыхтел?

Comment: в конкретном случае сервер вам только спасибо скажет за такое представление запроса.

Comment: Не могли бы вы аргументировать конкретнее? В чём преимущество `LEFT OUTER JOIN` перед `INNER JOIN` в этом конкретном случае? Лучше даже добавить это в ответ.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin В данном конкретном случае LEFT JOIN на стадии WHERE optimization самопреобразуется в INNER (а на старых версиях даже этого не будет, там WHERE optimization выполняется после LEFT JOIN optimization, а не в процессе). Никакого профита в принципе, только лишняя работа. Да плюс фиксированный порядок просмотра таблиц - но если это необходимо. гораздо проще добиться того же с помощью STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: спасибо, так глубоко этот вопрос никогда не копал, надо подучить. В общем вопрос был сформировать рабочий запрос.